# Rails - Fetch data using a condition in order

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a model called `HiringProcedureStage` which has a column called `order_by` what I am trying to do is fetch the data in order of `order_by` but if this is empty then fetch the data in order of `created_at` date

This is what I tried but it does not seem to order the data by `created_at` if `order_by` is missing.

```
HiringProcedureStage.find_all_by_hiring_procedure_id_and_deleted(self.job.hiring_procedure, false, :order => "order_by ASC" || "created_at ASC", :limit => 1 )
```

Comment: Is this plain ActiveRecord or do you use a plugin? `"order_by ASC" || "created_at ASC"` seems wrong unless the `||` is overloaded.

Comment: @Wukerplank it is a plain ActiveRecord, I am not sure what do you mean when you say a plugin

Comment: If you write `"order_by ASC" || "created_at ASC"` then it will always use `"order_by ASC"`. Is there a `order_by` variable you are trying to use? then the code should look like this: `..., :order => order_by || "created_at ASC"), ...`

Comment: @Wukerplank order_by is not a variable, its a column in table just like created_at

Comment: okay, but how would you decide programmatically if you want to order by `order_by` or by `created_at`?